# How to hide page navigation bar and header for a specific page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a page without the page navigation bar and header, but I want it for every other pages - how can I achieve this?

I've added this code to the page's .css file but it ends up hiding the page nav bar and header for every page':

```
.navbar-custom {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

header{
  display: none;
}
```

Screenshot of the current page:

[image]

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you set an `id` to the `body` element on this specific page.
Then you can set the same rules with the `#page-id` prefix.

For example:

```
#page-id .navbar-custom {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#page-id header{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also make a separate stylesheet for the page you want it to be hidden